# Node.js mssql error: tedious deprecated The default value for `config.options.enableArithAbort` will change from `false` to `true`

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

I get the error below. How do I fix it?

> tedious deprecated The default value for `config.options.enableArithAbort` will change from `false` to `true` in the next major version of `tedious`. Set the value to `true` or `false` explicitly to silence this message. node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:61:23

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change your database config options to the following:

```
     var config = {
      user: 'username',
      password: 'password',
      server: 'localhost', 
      database: 'databasename',
      "options": {
        "encrypt": true,
        "enableArithAbort": true
        }
   };
```

read issue details here: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/976

Comment: I confirm, using latest mssql as of January 2021. Exactly. Thank you.

Comment: This worked. I needed to explicitly define both `encrypt` and `enableArithAbort`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me :

```js
const config = {

    user: 'sa',

    password: '<YOUR_PASSWORD>',

    server: '<COMPUTER_NAME>\\SQLEXPRESS',

    database: '<DBNAME>',

    requestTimeout: 180000, // for timeout setting

    connectionTimeout: 180000, // for timeout setting

      "options": {

        "encrypt": false, // need to stop ssl checking in case of local db

        "enableArithAbort": true

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to tedious [docs](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html)
and
[SET ARITHABORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
enableArithAbort: true // Ends a query when an overflow or divide-by-zero error occurs during query execution.  

encrypt: true, // A boolean determining whether or not the connection will be encrypted. Set to true if you're on Windows Azure.
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of setting in config in your project, set the value in node_modules
node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js.

```
options: {
   enableArithAbort: true,//<----------set this to true
   port: parseInt(config.port, 10),
   database: config.database,
   trustServerCertificate: true
}
```

Comment: and with the next npm install on another pc the problem is there again